# CxViewer IntelliJ Plugin not working for Checkmarx account with user/pass

Tags: intellij-idea, checkmarx

I followed the documentation on page and not able to make it working,
https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/1339490445/Setting+Up+the+IntelliJ+Plugin+v9.0.0+and+up

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got it working after adding required certs on machine.